# How to map PC (ARMv5) address to source code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, arm, alignment

I'm developing on an ARM9E processor running Linux. Sometimes my application crashes with the following message :

> [  142.410000] Alignment trap: rtspserverd (996) PC=0x4034f61c
>   Instr=0xe591300c Address=0x0000000d FSR 0x001

How can I translate the PC address to actual source code? In other words, how can I make sense out of this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [objdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump). Dump your executable, then search for `4034f61c:`.
The `-x`, `--disassemble`, and `-l` options are particularly useful.

Comment: I am cross compiling from x86 ubuntu to arm, is there anything I should be aware of?

Comment: You'll need to use an arm-specific objdump. It should have come with your gcc toolchain (assuming you're using gcc). `--architecture=<arch>` and `-i` to list available architectures.

Comment: Or `addr2line -e  <file> 0x4034f61c` (requires debug information).

Comment: ok it worked. In fact, I needed to grep for e591300c instead of the PC instruction and "grep -A 5 -B 5" the output

Comment: Ok I don't think that e591300c was the right thing to watch for, its the ldr instruction and not the place where it crashed.

Comment: followup : Yeah it works with the objdump from my toolchain, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can turn on listings in the compiler and tell the linker to produce a map file. The map file will give you the meaning of the absolute addresses up to the function where the problem occurs, while the listing will help you pinpoint the exact location of the exception within the function.

For example in `gcc` you can do

```
gcc -Wa,-a,-ad -c foo.c > foo.lst
```

to produce a listing in the file `foo.lst`.

`-Wa,` sends the following options to the assembler (`gas`).

`-a` tells `gas` to produce a listing on standard output.

`-ad` tells `gas` to omit debug directives, which would otherwise add a lot of clutter.

The option for the GNU linker to produce a map file is `-M` or `--print-map`. If you link with `gcc` you need to pass the option to the linker with an option starting with `-Wl,`, for example `-Wl,-M`.

Alternatively you could also run your application in the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) and look at the stack dump after the crash with the `bt` command.

Comment: I'm using an arm toolchain and these options don't seem to be recognized

Comment: There should be something analogous in other compilers.

Comment: This should work with GNU toolchains independently of the target architecture. I just checked for `avr-gcc` (I wanted to generate these files anyway as part of the regular build).

Comment: Even with standard gcc I get "Unrecognized command line option -Wa"

Comment: @Eric Have you added a space after "-Wa" before the comma? The option is "-Wa," and is documented here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Assembler-Options.html#Assembler-Options